# How To Change Sub-View From Full Screen To Action Sheet Style

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a view that when a button is clicked, it brings up a subview that looks like the following image.

However there is much wasted space here.  How can I change it so that the subview is like an action sheet, just the picker with a done/cancel button right above the picker like is commonly done.

Currently this view is a UIView in IB, and is animated in with the following code:

```
- (IBAction)dateButtonPressed
{
    [dateView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [self.view addSubview:dateView];
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        [dateView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the frame of dateview. Instead of (0,0,320,480) (in case of iPhone), use (0, 270, 320, 210), if the height of your view is to be kept as 210 (270 = 480-210)

In case you want the Cancel and Done buttons to come up in the same view, create a UIView with the date picker and a toolbar on top of it with Done and Cancel buttons. And add this UIView to your view again with an adjusted "y" in the CGRect that you pass for the dateView's frame.